# Who can vote in the elections?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

How much reputation does one need in order to vote?

I have read through the election page, and I have either missed it completely, or it is not mentioned there.

Comment: On each phase (clicking on the tabs under the summary), a yellow box on the right side will tell you the minimum rep needed.

Comment: [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need 150 reputation to vote in the election, for both the primary and the final election.